# Telerik WinForms Radgriview filter boolean

Tags: telerik, boolean, filtering, radgridview

I am using Telerik WinForms RadGridView Control, I have set up Excel-like filtering, everything in fine, but I have a little problem. When I am filtering a Boolean field, in filter popup their are values: "True" and "False". Is it possible to change them on something more user-friendly, like "Yes" and "No" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People from Telerik helped me to solve this problem :)

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/winforms-radgriview-filter-boolean.aspx

To avoid a link only answer which isn't ideal in case the link goes down.  Here is the relevant code to solve the problem:

```
void radGridView1_FilterPopupRequired(object sender, FilterPopupRequiredEventArgs e)
{
    RadListFilterPopup popup = e.FilterPopup as RadListFilterPopup;
    if (popup != null)
    {
        RadTreeView tree = popup.MenuTreeElement.TreeView;
        tree.NodeAdded += new RadTreeView.RadTreeViewEventHandler(tree_NodeAdded);
        popup.PopupClosed += new RadPopupClosedEventHandler(popup_PopupClosed);
    }
}

void popup_PopupClosed(object sender, RadPopupClosedEventArgs args)
{
    RadListFilterPopup popup = sender as RadListFilterPopup;
    popup.MenuTreeElement.TreeView.NodeAdded -= new RadTreeView.RadTreeViewEventHandler(tree_NodeAdded);
}

void tree_NodeAdded(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Text == "False")
    {
        e.Node.Text = "No";
    }
    else if (e.Node.Text == "True")
    {
        e.Node.Text = "Yes";
    }
}
```